# draw retangular and scale to fit screen

Tags: android, scale, draw

This is my little app. It looks perfect in my device but when I use it in               another device with another size screen the rectangle does not fit the screen    to the edge.I try to convert pix to dp but it does not work great.

```
public class MyView extends View  {
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
Paint paint;
private Rect rectangle;
Paint paint2;
private Rect rectangle2;
Paint paint3;
private Rect rectangle3;
Paint paint4;
private Rect rectangle4;
Paint paint5;
private Rect rectangle5;
Paint paint6;
private Rect rectangle6;
Paint paint7;
private Rect rectangle7;
Paint paint8;
private Rect rectangle8;
Paint paint9;
private Rect rectangle9;
Paint paint10;
private Rect rectangle10;
Paint paint11;
private Rect rectangle11;
Paint paint12;
private Rect rectangle12;
Paint paint13;
private Rect rectangle13;
Paint paint14;
private Rect rectangle14;
Paint paint15;
private Rect rectangle15;
Paint paint16;
private Rect rectangle16;
Paint colorPicker1;
private Rect rectangleRed;
Paint colorPicker2;
private Rect rectangleYellow;
Paint colorPicker3;
private Rect rectangleBlue;
Paint colorPicker4;
private Rect rectangleWhite;
int xStored;
int yStored;
int colorStore1;

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    Log.i(TAG, "hola "+ screen);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle = new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    paint2 = new Paint();
    paint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle2 = new Rect(110, 0, 250, 100);
    paint3 = new Paint();
    paint3.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle3 = new Rect(260, 0, 340, 100);
    paint4 = new Paint();
    paint4.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle4 = new Rect(350, 0, 480, 100);
    paint5 = new Paint();
    paint5.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle5 = new Rect(0, 110, 100, 260);
    paint6 = new Paint();
    paint6.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle6 = new Rect(110, 110, 250, 260);
    paint7 = new Paint();
    paint7.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle7 = new Rect(260, 110, 340, 260);
    paint8 = new Paint();
    paint8.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle8 = new Rect(350, 110, 480, 260);
    paint9 = new Paint();
    paint9.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle9 = new Rect(0, 270, 100, 340);
    paint10 = new Paint();
    paint10.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle10 = new Rect(110, 270, 250, 340);
    paint11 = new Paint();
    paint11.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle11 = new Rect(260, 270, 340, 340);
    paint12 = new Paint();
    paint12.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle12 = new Rect(350, 270, 480, 340);
    paint13 = new Paint();
    paint13.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle13 = new Rect(0, 350, 100, 440);
    paint14 = new Paint();
    paint14.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle14 = new Rect(110, 350, 250, 440);
    paint15 = new Paint();
    paint15.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle15 = new Rect(260, 350, 340, 440);
    paint16 = new Paint();
    paint16.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle16 = new Rect(350, 350, 480, 440);

    colorPicker1 = new Paint();
    colorPicker1.setColor(Color.RED);
    rectangleRed= new Rect(0, 580 , 120+ screen, 680);
    colorPicker2 = new Paint();
    colorPicker2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    rectangleYellow = new Rect(120+ screen, 580, 240+ screen2, 680);
    colorPicker3 = new Paint();
    colorPicker3.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    rectangleBlue = new Rect(240+ screen3, 580, 360,680 );
    colorPicker4 = new Paint();
    colorPicker4.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    rectangleWhite = new Rect(360+ screen, 580, 480+ screen, 680);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(BLACK);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle2, paint2);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle3, paint3);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle4, paint4);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle5, paint5);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle6, paint6);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle7, paint7);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle8, paint8);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle9, paint9);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle10, paint10);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle11, paint11);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle12, paint12);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle13, paint13);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle14, paint14);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle15, paint15);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle16, paint16);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangleRed, colorPicker1);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangleYellow,colorPicker2 );
    canvas.drawRect(rectangleBlue,colorPicker3 );
    //canvas.drawRect(rectangleWhite,colorPicker4 );
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    xStored = x; yStored=y;
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

    }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            if(rectangleRed.contains(x,y)){
            colorStore1 = colorPicker1.getColor();
                              }
            if(rectangleYellow.contains(x,y)){
                colorStore1 = colorPicker2.getColor();
            }
            if (rectangleBlue.contains(x,y)){
                colorStore1 = colorPicker3.getColor();
            }
            if (rectangleWhite.contains(x,y)){
                colorStore1 = colorPicker4.getColor();
            }
        if(rectangle.contains(x,y)){
            paint.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle2.contains(x,y)){
            paint2.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle3.contains(x,y)){
            paint3.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle4.contains(x,y)){
            paint4.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle5.contains(x,y)){
            paint5.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle6.contains(x,y)){
            paint6.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle7.contains(x,y)){
            paint7.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle8.contains(x,y)){
            paint8.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle9.contains(x,y)){
            paint9.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle10.contains(x,y)){
            paint10.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle11.contains(x,y)){
            paint11.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle12.contains(x,y)){
            paint12.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle13.contains(x,y)){
            paint13.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle14.contains(x,y)){
            paint14.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle15.contains(x,y)){
            paint15.setColor(colorStore1);
        }
        if(rectangle16.contains(x,y)){
            paint16.setColor(colorStore1);
        }

    }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

    }
    this.postInvalidate();
    return true;
  }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the getWidth() and getHeight() methods of View to get width and height at runtime, matching the actual screen.